# Place cursor on next line when semi-colon is pressed

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, jtextpane

When a user presses the semi-colon key, I would like the semi-colon to stay on the same line but the move the cursor down. For example,

**What I want**

> example text;  <-- semi-colon been pressed and entered
>
> | <--- cursor moved to here

My present code, the semi colon moves down and the cursor is placed next to it, like so:

**What I have**

> example text
>
> ;| <-- cursor and semi-colon go to a new line

Thank you.

**SSCCE**:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Example {

private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private final JTextPane editor = new JTextPane();

public Example() {
    frameStuff();
    newLineOnSemiColonPress();
}

private void newLineOnSemiColonPress() {
    InputMap input = editor.getInputMap();
    String INSERT_BREAK = "insert-break";
    KeyStroke semi = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SEMICOLON");
    input.put(semi, INSERT_BREAK);
}

private void frameStuff() {
    editor.setFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 13));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
    frame.getContentPane().add(editor);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Example();
}
}
```

Comment: Just make the cursor go right (INSERT_RIGHT_ARROW?), then insert the line break. Alternatively, you can handle the newLineOnSemicolonPress *after* you insert the semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to bind adding the break to when you release the semi-colon key, instead of when you first press it:

```
private void newLineOnSemiColonPress() {
    InputMap input = editor.getInputMap();
    String INSERT_BREAK = "insert-break";
    KeyStroke semi = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released SEMICOLON");
    input.put(semi, INSERT_BREAK);
}
```

If you haven't read it yet, there's a good [tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) with more information about how to use key bindings.

Comment: Works how I want it, I cannot believe I missed that in the documentation. Will accept when it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with your code or Java very much, but the problem is that you are doing things in the wrong order.
Either insert the newline after the semicolon is inserted, or just do a makeshift fix by moving the cursor right.

Maybe something like this:

```
private void newLineOnSemiColonPress() {
    InputMap input = editor.getInputMap();
    String INSERT_BREAK = "insert-break";
    KeyStroke semi = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SEMICOLON");
    input.put(semi, INSERT_RIGHT_ARROW);
    input.put(semi, INSERT_BREAK);
}
```

or going back in your code and ensuring that you handle character insertion before the call to newLineOnSemicolonPress will work for you. (As pointed out, this could be done by handling the event with on_key_release)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but azurefrog's answer is ideal.